# New user herobox content blurb is way out of date

Tags: bug, status-completed

The "herobox" banner presented to new users has content that is way out of date (at least a couple of years)!

The banner says there are "4.7 million users", but currently there are over 6.2 million.

[image: herobox]

From the [user leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow) page:

[image: leagues]

---

I assume that keeping the user count stats (which we should be very proud of!) fresh for banners on all sites is not done regularly/automatically. It would be quite a job to do them all manually. May I suggest that once per month/week stats for all banners are updated automatically using a single process.

Interestingly, the [All sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) page has correct current stats. Perhaps the banner update can piggyback on whatever process keeps those stats up to date.

Comment: brb putting a + after that 4.7. #fixitonce

Comment: Maybe the leagues count unregistered users, while the herobox notice doesn't? @Adam?

Comment: @Adam how about doing a quality job and periodically generating it automatically, say once every month?

Comment: @ShadowWizard No idea, but it's conceivable that the copy we haven't touched in a long time is out of date while signups are going up.

Comment: @Bohemian Hey now, what kind of shop do you think we run here?

Comment: @Adam you're the one who said adding "+" would fix the problem once and for all... **without a smiley** :)

Comment: To be fair, it *would* fix the problem... :)

Comment: @Adam you're thinking like a programmer, not a normal person... *or* a marketing person

Comment: Come on, man, I added a smiley that time. ;)

Comment: Follow McDonald's lead: "millions and millions".

Comment: It's possible that 4.7 million programmers are indeed helping each other, as stated in the copy, while the other 1.5 million are listening to rap music and competing at cup stacking. Has anyone performed any conclusive poll on this? Without data we can assume nothing.

Comment: @darren that did occur to me after asking the question. I suspect the true number of "programmers helping" is far fewer than even 1 million. Nevertheless, we can plausibly claim the full quota if we attach stronger significance to the unqualified "community of" part of the sentence and less to the qualifying parts. There's lies, damn lies and statistics.

Comment: They are probably only counting the *active* users, whatever that means.

Comment: @Knu I guess that number would be much lower then. As you can see in the question, only around 5% of registered users have more than 200 rep points. This is still not the actual number of active users, but it shows that there are a lot of accounts which asked a question once and never came back (or didn't even asked something).

Comment: @Tom the read-only users are not accounted for in your definition.

Comment: @tom even users who only ask 1 question and do nothing else still help. They help by creating a place that millions of (usually unregistered) visitors to the site can find an answer.

Comment: Related? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/310847/1007939

Comment: 4.7 M questions is how many there should, still, be :p

Comment: You have a diamond, you can fix this ...

Comment: @Bohemian I mean _active_ users. Users who have asked one question and weren't online for months/years aren't active in my consideration. This doesn't say anything about the helpfulness of these inactive users. Measuring the latter can be quite hard :P.

Comment: We live in a post-factual society where anything goes. Just make it 4.7 billion and be done with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number will be calculated directly starting with the next deployment (with caching, so you know what to blame for further errors).

Building out right now